# How to find similar unique lines in two csv files using Python

Tags: python, regex, text-files

I want to count number of similar and dissimilar entries in two csv (tab delimited) files.

I have been trying to use python [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) to get this done. 
Below is simplified version how the two input files look. They are very big and has many columns.

FileA

```
 ABC1 ABC2    SYMBOL EXCHANGE  NAME    ABC2  ABC3   
 234   f24     AAPL   NYSE     APPLE Inc.
 23f3  ef23    ab3c    jjm     Google     
 sf2d  df23    xyz     tsx     YourCompany
```

FileB

```
Exchange  Symbol  Name
 Tok      aapl     Apple Jap.
 NYSE     QUAL     Qualcom inc.
 NYSE     GOOG     Google
```

Rule to find similarity:

1. First check if Exchange and Symbol matches. If it matches then you got a match
2. If it didn't match then check for matching name. If name matches, then you got a match.

ABC1, ABC2 columns are there just for demonstration purpose, please ignore them when comparing entries.

The reason, I cannot solely check for names because, most company names have different prefixes/suffixes on different exchanges or they are in different language. But exchange and symbols are in English only in these two files.

Sample Output for above example:

```
FileA and FileB has 2 number of common companies.
FileA has 1 number of companies which are not in FileB
FileB has 1 number of companies which are not in FileA
```

I am new to python, so far I got diff code working, but still long way to go. Thought to put this question here.

```
import difflib

diff = difflib.ndiff(open("fileA").readlines(), open("fileB").readlines())

try:
    while 1:
        print diff.next(),
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say all you need is one dictionary per each file, mapping company name to an (exchange, ticker) tuple.

Common elements and elements unique to file 1:

```
common_elements = {}
unique_to_file_1 = {}
for key, value in file1_dict.iteritems():
  if key in file2_dict.keys() or value in file2_dict.values():
    common_elements[key] = value
  else:
    unique_to_file_1[key] = value
```

Elements unique to file 2:

```
unique_to_file_2 = {}
for key, value in file2_dict.iteritems():
  if key not in common_elements.keys() and value not in common_elements.values():
    unique_to_file_2[key] = value
```

I trust you do know how to create those two dictionaries from CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer without knowing whether your data contains duplicates and how you want to deal with them.

Set operations are very fast, so I suggest parsing one file into two sets, and looping through the rows in the other file to implement your comparison criteria.

```
import csv
alist, blist = [], []

with open("fileA.tsv", "rb") as fileA:
    reader = csv.reader(fileA, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        alist.append(row)
with open("fileB.tsv", "rb") as fileB:
    reader = csv.reader(fileB, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        blist.append(row)

se_set_a = set([(row[2], row[3]) for row in alist])
name_set_a = set([row[4].strip() for row in alist])
symbol_exchange_matches = []
name_matches = []
for row in blist:
    if (row[1], row[0]) in se_set_a:
        symbol_exchange_matches.append((row[1], row[0]))
    elif row[2].strip() in name_set_a:
        name_matches.append(row[2])

matches = symbol_exchange_matches + name_matches
print "FileA and FileB have %i number of common companies." % (len(set(matches)),)
```

Using your example data, I only find one common company: "Google" by name. Apple does not match given your criteria.